# Log in session with specific commands

Tags: ubuntu, pam

I would like to build a service program which allow user specific command in Ubuntu lightdm loggin page.

When the user tape for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, my session is open. I do know how to build a service program but I don't know how to autorise my service to be able to open my session ( and the command to do that).

Do I need to store my password somewhere on my computer or service priviliges are enough to open my session without my password?

Edit: In fact I found documentation on linux PAM.  Can I add a service on the /etc/pam.d/lightdm as sufficient which check if the user tape <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> ?